# How do you end code using either "quit" or hitting enter/ typing nothing?

Tags: python, if-statement

I need the code to end when I type either "quit" or nothing.

```
num_of_tik = 0
total = 0
while True:
  age = input("what is the age of the customer? (enter 'quit' when finshed)" )
  if age == "quit" and "":
    if num_of_tik >= 10:
      print("because you bought 10 or more tickets, you get 20% off!")
      total = total*0.8
    print("you bought", num_of_tik,"tickets")
    print("your total is", total, "dollars")
    break
  else:
    age = int(age)
    if age > 18:
      print("your ticket costs $20")
      total = total + 20
      num_of_tik = num_of_tik + 1
      
    else:
      if age > 13:
        print("your ticket costs $15")
        total = total + 15
        num_of_tik = num_of_tik + 1
      else:
        if age >= 3:
          print("your ticket costs $10")
          total = total + 10
          num_of_tik = num_of_tik + 1 
        else:
          print("your ticket is free")
          num_of_tik = num_of_tik + 1
```

I have tried using if age == "quit" or "": and that didn't work. I have also tried writing a new if statement. I don't know any other ways to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you have a logic error here:

```
if age == "quit" and "":
```

This should be:

```
if age == "quit" or age == "":
```

In your original form if the user types "quit" then `age == "quit"` is `True`, but `""` evaluates to `False` in Python, so your original `if` statement effectively becomes:

```
if True and False:
```

Not good. ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Like @rhurwitz pointed out, your if statement is malformed. That said, Generally when one variable needs to be compared to multiple values in an or-type statement, I prefer to not use 'or' at all:

```
if age in ("quit", ""):
   #conditional code
```

Answer (score -1):

There a minor error in the if condition;
instead of :
if age == "quit" and ""

it should be
if age == "quit" or ""